# SQL Selecting values from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1
ID-NAME
1-Name1
2-Name2

Table2
ID-NAME
1-Name3
4-Name4
```

I want to select all name values, where ID=1 (witch in this case would return 'Name1' and 'name3'). If the values have the same name, i want it to show just 1 record.

Something like:

```
SELECT NAME FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE ID = 1
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should look into using `UNION`:

```
SELECT NAME FROM Table1 WHERE Id = 1
UNION
SELECT NAME FROM Table2 WHERE Id = 1
```

Good luck.